# Databases for chess games

Tags: sql, database, nosql, chess

A previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3611473/database-to-choose-for-game) wanted to save each move to a database as a game of chess plays out. And asked what database to use to do this. Various possibilities were given:

MongoDb, CouchDb, MySql, SQLite

One answer in particular mentioned a traditional one to many mapping:

> The only advantage I can see to a mongodb or couchdb is that you could conceivably store the entire match in a single record, thus making your data a little simpler. You wouldn't have to do the traditional one to many mapping between moves table and a game table.

What exactly does this mean and what would this look like in say PostgreSql so I have a concrete idea of what this means?

Comment: You quoted a NoSQL example, and then asked what it would look like in SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below example Entity Relationship Diagram based on SQL 2005, but with some tweaks to datatypes it can be transferred to MySql or PostgreSql.

[image]

Comment: Going back to the previous question that I linked to. Would using this over say CouchDb make sense for chess?

Comment: It depends on what kind of queries are you going to make to it, and volume of the data, and personal preference ( which one easier to use for you ). There is a link where performance differences are discussed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1693412/couchdb-vs-mysql-speed

Comment: For chess what would be the benefits of having the game stored in multiple rows across multiple tables in sql vs storing everything in one chunk (or document)?